# SNS Notifications for 'Old' Guard Duty Findings?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I had previously set up an SNS topic to send emails regarding Guard Duty findings -- however, only "new" findings get pushed to the SNS topic. Is there a way to have all Guard Duty findings be pushed through a notification pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're asking is if you can resend Guard Duty findings to an SNS topic.  The short answer is that there's no built in way to do this.

Notwithstanding this, you can achieve this by writing a short script to get the findings for your detector, in your preferred programming language, and then pushing the findings to SNS again, manually.

Since I don't know what language you write or how you'll be interacting with the API, I'll refer you directly to the [GuardDuty API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/guardduty/latest/ug/guardduty_api_ref.html) which has all the info you need about which methods you'll need to call. At a high level, you'll want to first `ListFindings` so you have the FindingId's of all the findings, and then `GetFindings` for the details of each, and then publish the result of `GetFindings` to your SNS topic which will send you the email.